# How to perform aggregation in morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have a `List` of an object and I need to perform a query in `Morphia` to get the unique result from another embedding `List` of `String` in given object.

## Object Class:

```
@Entity
public class Fruits {
  @NotNull private Long id;
  @NotNull private List<String> categories;
}
```

## Data in Json Format:

Fruits:

```
 {[
  "id": 1234566,
  "categories": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
 ],
 [
  "id": 32434,
  "categories": ["A", "C", "E", "F"]
 ],
 [
  "id": 32434,
  "categories": ["A", "L", "M", "N"]
 ] 
}
```

The result of aggregation supposed to be:

```
[A,C,B,D,E,F,L,M,N]
```

The output is in sorted form. How can I achieve this in morphia? I tried to search on official documentation but couldn't find the hint.

Any help or hint would be appreciable. Thanks

## EDIT-1

```
List<Fruits> fruitList = fruitControllerDao.search(fruitList);

List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
datastore.createAggregation(Fruits.class)
         .unwind("categories")
         .group(Group.id(Group.grouping("categories")))
         .sort(Sort.ascending("_id.categories"))
         .project(Projection.projection("_id").suppress(), 
          Projection.projection("categories", "_id.categories"))

         .aggregate(Category.class).forEachRemaining(categories::add);
```

and I have created

```
class Category {
   private String category;
}
```

Data in `fruitList` is unusable and I need to apply `aggregation` on the `fruitList` (Checkout the JSON Format) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to get unique & sort categories using aggregation pipeline.

Prepare Query Filter:

```
Query<Fruits> query = datastore.createQuery(Fruits.class);
Iterator<Fruits> fruitIterator = fruitList .iterator();
CriteriaContainer orQuery = query.or();
while(fruitIterator.hasNext()) {
      Fruits fruit = fruitIterator.next();
      orQuery.add(query.and(query.criteria("id").equal(fruit.getId()), query.criteria("categories").equal(fruit.getCategories())));
 }
```

The below query `$matches` on query filter and `$unwinds` the `categories` followed by `$group` to remove the duplicates and sorting. The last step is to read the value from grouping stage and `$project` into category field.

```
 List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
  datastore.createAggregation(Fruits.class)
        .match(query)
        .unwind("categories")
        .group(Group.id(Group.grouping("categories")))
        .sort(Sort.ascending("_id.categories"))
        .project(Projection.projection("_id").suppress(), Projection.projection("category", "_id.categories"))
        .aggregate(Category.class).forEachRemaining(categories::add);


class Category {
    private String category;
}
```

Update:

Mongo Shell Query

```
   [{ "$match" : { "$or" : [ { "$and" : [ { "_id" : 1234566} , { "categories" : [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D"]}]} , { "$and" : [ { "_id" : 32434} , { "categories" : [ "A" , "C" , "E" , "F"]}]} , { "$and" : [ { "_id" : 32434} , { "categories" : [ "A" , "L" , "M" , "N"]}]}]}}, { "$unwind" : "$categories"}, { "$group" : { "_id" : { "categories" : "$categories"}}}, { "$sort" : { "_id.categories" : 1}}, { "$project" : { "_id" : 0 , "category" : "$_id.categories"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `_id` refers to `Fruits.id` here. right?

Comment: You are welcome. No its the `_id` generated from `group`. Mongo shell query added for comparison & also added some explanation in the post.

Comment: I am trying to implement this code but got confused about where and How are you using the `Fruit` object data in above code. Could you please help me out here? I mean How can I apply this aggregation query on above Json?

Comment: The fruit object is needed by Morphia to collect the metadata defined by annotations. One such example is to read the collection name from `@Entity` annotations if you define one. 
Little bit more information here http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/aggregation/ Do you have the rest of the set up ? Are you not able to run the query ?

Comment: Ah! I think I misunderstood you. Please have a look at the `Edit-1` in the Question section.

Comment: My apologies here. I misunderstood your post. Edited answer to include the query filter.

Comment: Thanks, I will use above code in implementation. BTW `while(studentIterator.hasNext()) {` you wanted to say `while(fruitIterator.hasNext()) {`. right?